# How to change java collection selected position

Tags: java, collections

I working a android app.
I want change my ArrayList changed selected position.

sample;

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("item 1");
myList.add("item 2");
myList.add("item 3");
myList.add("item 4");
myList.add("item 5");
......
```

Now I want change "item 3"  to "item 3 changed"

please help. Thanx.

Comment: `MyList.set(2,"item 3 changed");`

Comment: If you want to be serious at programming in Java, use the Javadoc. Here it's simple: go to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html and skim the methods. You'll find the one you need.

Answer (score 3):

Your exact answer is:

```
MyList.set(2,"item 3 changed");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the `List` so that the position with the value `item3` now has the value `item 3 changed` you could also do this (without knowing beforehand the position in the `List`):

```
String searchFor="item3";
String replacement="item 3 changed";
myList.set(myList.indexOf(searchFor), replacement);
```

However, take into account that due to the immutable nature of the `String` class, the values of the `String` instance will not be changed, but instead the `List` will be holding a new, different `String` instance.

In other words, let's say String `s1` is in the third position in the `List`, and has the value `item3`. By using the code above, you're not changing the value of `s1`, but instead creating a new `String` `s2`, giving it value `item 3 changed` and assigning it to the third position in the `List`.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways:

1. The shorter one is: [**`Collections.replaceAll(List<T> list, T oldVal, T newVal)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#replaceAll%28java.util.List,%20T,%20T%29) function it will replace all of the occurrence of `oldVal` to `newVal`.

   ```
   Collections.replaceAll(myList, "item 3", "item 3 changed");
   ```
2. Another one is [**`ArrayList.set(index, E elm)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) function: which will set `elm` at the given `index`. Which you can get from `ArrayList.indexOf(E)` function.

Comment: @MustafaOlkun, As i always notify about the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to let them know how to use this site. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
myList.remove ("item 3"); // or myList.remove(2);
myList.add(2,"item 3 changed");
```

Comment: No need to `remove` and `add`. A simple `set` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` method

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
.....
myList.set(2,"item 3 changed");
```